# Does anyone else find the new banner ads REEAAALLY annoying?

Tags: feature-request, advertising

I'm horrified by the banner ads that are now appearing in the middle of the page. My love for SO is strong, but these challenge it a bit. I find them very distracting. Does anyone else hate them as much as I do? It wouldn't be too hard to convince me to shell out a few bucks every month to keep them away, if it comes to that.

Comment: What banner ads are you seeing on which site?

Comment: I've yet to see any new ugly ones as well. Perhaps you didn't realize the banners all along because you've never browsed the pages as a new user (since the banners kicked in) and when you did, it can be a 'shocker' :)

Comment: Forget paying a subscription fee! Simply purchase an item from my Amazon Wish List (http://www.amazon.com/wishlist/W8SQGE56QHGG) and I will *personally* have the ads removed from your account within 2 business days!

Comment: Why do you need to shell out? Adblock is free.

Comment: I don't NEED to shell out, but SO is enormously valuable to me, and I think the creators deserve to be rewarded for what they've done. So I'd be fine with shelling out a little. Well, actually, the people I should be REALLY grateful for are all of those who've answered my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be seeing it outside your normal account, since at 200 rep you shouldn't see them anymore.

Comment: Correction at 200 you get reduced adverts.

Comment: @MrStatic, you're right about adverts in general, but I was refering to banner ads, which was what the OP was asking about.

Comment: Yup, that was it. I wasn't signed in.