# Add Sponsored Links to Sidebar

Tags: feature-request, advertising, stack-exchange

I would like to request.... additional advertising.

I know, right?

The idea for this feature request first came about as part of my recent attempts to get a guy who [may or may not be spamming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46793/problem-user-spamming-personal-library) to purchase advertising on Stack Overflow in the form of a sponsored tag. One problem I've run into (and it might just be in my own head) is the value of the sponsored tag.

It appears that a sponsored tag involves two basic forms of value: a logo on the tag itself, and sponsored links for the tag that appear on the questions of a particular tag pages. I suggest that additional value could be had from a sponsored tag if the sponsored links also appear on questions that are tagged with the sponsored tag. I suggest putting it in the side bar thus:

[image: See the big red circle]

Unfortunately, the page I chose didn't have a side-bar ad, but I'd suggest putting the sponsored links section below the sidebar ad for the page. I chose the page I did because it had two sponsored tags, and that leads to a functionality discussion for such a case. I'd suggest displaying only a few sponsored links with a user-selectable expansion to display all sponsored links. In the case of more than one sponsored tag appearing in the section, chose one sponsored link (randomly) from each sponsored tag and display all of them in the user-selected expansion.

I feel this would be a large-benefit change, adding value to sponsored tag options while remaining benign to the end user. It takes up little real-estate and increases the chances of the links being displayed, which could translate directly into revenue for the advertiser and SOFU in general.

I've already searched for suggestions similar to this and came up empty; apologies if I missed, I swear I did the research!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But... but... Stack Overflow is already [covered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39656/does-anyone-else-find-the-new-banner-ads-reeaaally-annoying) [with](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33875/are-there-too-many-corporate-tag-logos-on-so) [ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41131/do-stack-overflow-family-sites-have-too-many-ads-closed) as is. Have a look, see:

> [image]

--
It's an interesting idea, though. While I'm sure our sponsors wouldn't *mind* having more links, there haven't been any complaints and we have had a high renewal rate on tags.

Will this benefit the user experience? I don't know... probably not?

Will this drive more revenue? Maybe... but probably not that much. I'd have to really do some research on it.

My 2 cents: if it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: My 2 cents: 1. Change something; 2. If you see a drop-off, revert the change and go back to step 1; 3. If the change is positive, keep it and go back to step 1.

Comment: @Alex: Heh... Well, you are the marketing dude, so that's my answer. I personally think it would drive revenue without *hindering* user experience.

Comment: ...oh snap! I just noticed the center image in your graphic :)

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: Unsurprising that it took you that long. There's a lot of cruft in there.