# Big Banner ad for DevExpress

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, advertising

Since yesterday, I'm getting a Really Big Banner ad for DevExpress in a prime location.  Also several tags got an icon at the same time.

Am I supposed to see this banner?  Looking at other [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40639/woah-sf-has-top-banner-ads) [threads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39656/does-anyone-else-find-the-new-banner-ads-reeaaally-annoying), I have way more than the 200 rep needed to get these banners suppressed.  Yes, I'm logged in.

[alt text http://img576.imageshack.us/img576/8251/bannershot.png](http://img576.imageshack.us/img576/8251/bannershot.png)

Comment: Odd, I haven't seen this banner on either of my machines, and I'm pretty sure I don't have any ad-blocking enabled for Stack Overflow.  You *sure* you didn't get logged out?

Comment: Screenshot? I'm also not seeing a banner.

Comment: The dev express boasts **free** stuff.  Why are you complaining about that?

Comment: @justin I already have the stuff I need. I don't want to waste cycles looking at ads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, as it were, expected behavior. The large banner is an advertisement for a sponsored tag. It'll appear whenever you're focused on a tag that is sponsored (and in this case, you have c#, winforms, and visual-studio-2010). It cannot be suppressed by high enough reputation.

Comment: Almost all, or maybe all, sponsored tags have banners in that top ad space if you are viewing questions with a sponsored tag (by clickin on a tag).  That DevExpress icon on the C# tag is larger than the actual text on the tag, which is why I noticed it more than usual.

Comment: @Bratch Yes, all sponsored tags will have this whenever you are focused on that tag.

Comment: Jon Skeet having to look at ads, I wonder how that turns out.

Comment: @Hans Jon is a pretty level-headed guy, I honestly think he won't care.